# maildrop refilter already existing inbox

Tags: email

I'm using maildrop and spamassassin from .qmail (on an uberspace.de host), and modified my filter settings.
now I want to "refilter" my inbox, because it contains about 5k spam mails, which would be correctly handled now.
is there any way to run maildrop manually, using my existing inbox (or a copy of it) as the input, so it filters them all again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Maildrop, but it is a delivery agent.  Unless maildrop is responsible in your set-up for passing mail through spamassassin, then it's most likely not maildrop you should be calling, at least not directly.

You might want to take a look at procmail, which is a very flexible tool for taking mail on STDIN and executing various rules on it.  eg you'd want to first pass the mail through spamassassin to get new spam headers and then deliver them.  Procmail is often used as a delviery agent itself, but I'm sure you can have it pass mail to maildrop for delivery if that's important.  eg maildrop might be doing some indexing stuff to make your IMAP system more efficient.

---

OK, so if maildrop does the filtering, then you should be able to just pipe your mail to maildrop.

Exactly how you do that depends a bit on the mailbox format you currently have the email in.  Maildrop can deliver to either mbox (one file per mail directory) or maildir (one file per email), but maildir is the more likely format.  Let me know if you are using mbox, but for the moment I'll assume maildir.

within a given maildir directory, there are subdirectories for `new`, `cur` and `tmp`.  Probably your messages are all in `cur`, but if you haven't accessed the mailbox since mail was delivered, it might be in `new`.  I'd avoid trying to process stuff in `tmp`, which should be empty.

You want to do something like this, in bash:

```
sudo -i
cd [your Maildir]
find cur new -type f | while read FILENAME ; do
  su vmail /usr/bin/maildrop -d [recipient] < "$FILENAME"
done
```

This is based on looking at a debian system, though as I say, I don't use maildrop, and this is untested.  If using postfix, look for the `maildrop` entry in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and you should get the right user and path and so on for your OS distribution.

docs for maildrop here: http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop.html

Be aware though, that spamassassin will have much less to work with here than for the original delivery.  eg it can't look up the sending IP in blacklists, scrutinise the (mis)use of the SMTP protocol, etc.

Comment: "maildrop is responsible in your set-up for passing mail through spamassassin" that's the case. also I can't use procmail, because the filters are defined in maildrop's ~/.mailfilter config.

Comment: I bet the original info for spamassassin to parse can't be extracted from the headers? (i'd have to parse them anyway, because `[recipient]` could be multiple addresses)